# How can I add columns from a data.table to a second data.table, by two identifiers?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table, defined as `dt1` in the code below:

```
set.seed(1)
temp = rnorm(365,280,10)
id <- seq(10000, 10099, by = 1)
day <-  seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"),as.Date("2013-12-31"), by = "day")
dt1 <- as.data.table(cbind(sample(id,1000, replace = T),rep(sample(day,10),100),sample(temp,1000, replace = T)))
setnames(dt1, c("id","day","temp"))
dt1[,day := as.Date(day, origin = "1970-01-01")]
dt1 <- dt1[,month := month(day)]
```

I have defined a function to calculate a quantile for a given vector of values:

```
quantile_function <- function(x){
  p = ecdf(x)
  return(p(x))
}
```

I then calculated quantiles for each day, and have taken mean quantiles for each id, by month:

```
dt1[,temp_quantile_day := quantile_function(temp), by = day]
dt1 <- dt1[,mean_quantile_month := mean(temp_quantile_day), by = .(id,month)]
```

The code above results in a unique value of `temp_quantile_month` for each id, for each month, as below:

```
unique_dt <- unique(dt1[,.(id,mean_quantile_month, month)], by = c('id','month'))
```

Now i create a second data.table, with a day and month for each `id`:

```
dt2 <- as.data.table(expand.grid(id,day))
setnames(dt2,c("id","day"))
dt2 <- dt2[,month := month(day)]
```

I want to assign each `temp_quantile_month` value, by `id` and `month`, to the appropriate id, by month.  Iwant the same value assigned to each day of the month, even if the id does not have a temp value for a given day. I have tried this:

```
dt2 <- unique_dt[dt2, on = c("id","month")]
```

but I only get `NAs` in the resulting data.table:

```
id mean_quantile_month month        day
1: 10000                  NA     1 2013-01-01
2: 10001                  NA     1 2013-01-01
3: 10002                  NA     1 2013-01-01
4: 10003                  NA     1 2013-01-01
5: 10004                  NA     1 2013-01-01
6: 10005                  NA     1 2013-01-01
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the only `NA`s. `unique_dt[dt2, on = .(id, month)]
          id mean_quantile_month month        day
    1: 10000                  NA     1 2013-01-01
    2: 10001           0.6500000     1 2013-01-01
    3: 10002                  NA     1 2013-01-01
    4: 10003           0.3800000     1 2013-01-01
    5: 10004           0.4800000     1 2013-01-01`

Comment: What is the version of data.table you used

Comment: @akrun: I'm using data.table v1.12.2, with R v3.5.1, on a windows 10 machine with 64-bit architecture. Also, in joining `unique_dt` to `dt2`, passing the on argument as `c("id","month")` seems to produce a different results from passing the argument as `.(id,month)`. The second version is close to what I want to achieve.

Comment: I have 1.12.2 as well, but the `R` version is `3.6.0`.  I get both to be the same output.  Note that I am not updating the resultss to `dt2 <- `

Comment: I'm updating R and moving my old packages to the new version..I'll be back in a while with an answer on how the update went.

Comment: I doubt it is the R version. Try re-running your reproducible example in a clean, empty R environment. During your trial/error, some dormant environment object may have changed.